# Query plan shows high negative value and the server slows down

Tags: sql-server, performance

My SQL Server 2016 had been presenting problems certain days, all process since the morning begins to run slowly than normally. Sometimes updating statistics works, sometimes not and had to reboot service. In query plan, when things go wrong with the "main" query, it shows a high negative value, after things start to work well, the query plan show normal values.

[image: statistics with problem]

[image: after all]

There is something else thing I could do and  somebody knows why sometimes update stats doesn't work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share the [execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/), view, and table definitions?

Comment: Has this problem started after migrating to 2016 ?Some time poorly written query which involve lot of data, work inconsistently.Like when cache get full then cardianlity estimation goes wrong ?May you should check compatiblity level of 2016

Comment: Yes, I started to view this behavior after migration to 2016. I switched the compatibility level to 130. You have reason involving a poorly query. I'm going to report that to developer team and leave database level on 100 again. I'll let you know what happen after all. Thank you

Comment: Any updates ? When you switched the compatibility level to 130 then what happened ?

Comment: Hello @KumarHarsh, After change it again to compatibility level 100 it had been working well. Thankyou so much